# Chrome always opens http://localhost:3000/user_sessions/new on launch

Tags: google-chrome, ruby-on-rails

Every time I launch Chrome on my Mac, it opens a tab with `http://localhost:3000/user_sessions/new`. I guess this has something to do with Ruby on Rails and perhaps a test server that a much more server-savvy friend once set up for a project years ago, but I have no idea where this is defined or how to get rid of it. Any ideas where to start looking?

Comment: Did you check the home settings on chrome?

Comment: Yes i did, and there it says "Continue where you left off" as usual. (For the record, I don't leave this tab hanging around so that it would be why it's opened every time. I do have the usual 40-60 other tabs to open, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you aren't locked by your company, go to

Chrome settings - On startup - open specific page or set of pages - set pages.

Comment: Nah, I have "Continue where you left off" there, as usual. The urge to open this strange page comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Try "Open the New Tab page" and write the result.

Comment: I have the usual 40, 50 or 60 tabs that I absolutely want to keep along when I boot my computer or my browser. So, no, I'm not going to want to lose them by choosing just an empty start page. I'm just wondering where this one defunct page always comes from.

Comment: @villapossu Try disabling add-ons to see what happens. I'd suggest safe mode as well